# Join VM to domain

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am using arm template to build Azure VM. Once the vm provisioning is complete it then join to domain. However, the join operation fails.

[image]

I tired to add the vm manually to the domain. It work with out any issue.

Please see the link for the template https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cUIIIFJpQHhesZXtf7-pfX_oTTq_C0NH

The c:\windowsazure\logs\plugins(or extensions)\domainjoin log file shows the following error

[image]

Thanks

Comment: i dont think its template related, can you login to the vm and grab logs `c:\windowsazure\logs\plugins(or extensions)\domainjoin` and paste into the question?

Comment: Sorted. The OU was wrong. In AD all computers are  under Computers container.

Answer (score 0):

in this case the error was due to attempt to join vm to a wrong OU.